# How to ignore a property when using @BindBean

Tags: java, jdbi

I'm using JDBI with this simple query:

```
@SqlQuery("SELECT id FROM myTable WHERE value = :bean.one")
int search(@BindBean("bean") MyBean bean);

public class Bean { 
  String one; 
  String two; 
  public String getTwo() { throw new IllegalStateException(); }
  // other methods omitted
}
```

Only the `one` property is used in the query, so I would expect this to work fine. Unfortunately, the default bean mapper first collects all properties from the bean, and later fills them in the query.

Can I tell JDBI to ignore the bean property or method so it won't be called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be considered a bug (or at least a papercut) in v2--please [report it to the team](https://github.com/jdbi/jdbi) if you'd like it fixed.

As a workaround, `Query.bindFromProperties(bean)` will ignore properties that are not in the query. If you rewrite your SQL method as a concrete/default method:

```
interface MyDao extends GetHandle {
  default int search(MyBean bean) {
    return getHandle().createQuery(
            "SELECT id FROM myTable WHERE value = :bean.one")
        .bindFromProperties(bean)
        .mapTo(int.class)
        .first();
  }
}
```

This has been fixed in the latest v3 alpha, for what it's worth.